# How to digitally sign request data in PHP

Tags: php, encryption

I need to digitally sign the digital signature using SHA1RSA how can I do that?

```
class MyEncryption
{

    public $pubkey = '...public key here...';

    public function encrypt($data)
    {
        if (openssl_public_encrypt($data, $encrypted, $this->pubkey))
            $data = base64_encode($encrypted);
        else
            throw new Exception('Unable to encrypt data. Perhaps it is bigger than the key size?');

        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you supposed to share your RSA key with the server? If neither part of the key is shared, how can the server in question verify that something's indeed signed since it can't compute the same result?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't handle that on application level. Using all the features of `ssl` (HTTPS) should work for you.